# variable assignment inside ajax success call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to collect data from a ajax request from a buch of URLs doing something like this:

```
        let allData = [];

        let dataURL = [];

        $('.pagn .pg').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-url')){
                dataURL.push("https://www.myweb.com/" + $(this).attr('data-url'));
            }
        })

        //dataURL.shift() //Remove first item from array
        dataURL.splice(dataURL.length-1,1); //Remove last item from array
        console.log(`COLLECTED URL`)
        console.log(dataURL)

        for(let i = 0;i<dataURL.length;i++){
            console.log(`Inside Loop`)
            getAndPopulateData(dataURL[i],i)
        }

        function getAndPopulateData(dataUrl,removeIndex){
            console.log(`Inside Ajasx`)
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:dataUrl,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(`Ajax successful`)
                    console.log(data.data.items)

                    allData.push(data.data.items)
                    dataURL.splice(removeIndex,1);
                    if(dataURL.length == 0){
                        console.log(`All elements have been removed`)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

I can see the data in my console coming from `console.log(data.data.items)` which takes about 2 seconds to appear. But when I check the allData variable it is just an empty array. Shouldn't everything inside the success function be processed synchronously?

Comment: Your `$.ajax` call is not synchronous.

Comment: But the variable assignment is happening inside success function which is synchronous

Comment: Apparently you have to declare allData with `var` keyword instead of `let`. I have no idea why. Will leave this question open for someone to answer

Comment: You didn't post the `console.log()` where you check the value, so I can't give any more suggestions.

Comment: I was checking on google console. I check the value by just typing `allData` which shows `[]` if I use the let keyword. But it returns an array with data if I use `var`

Comment: Well that means there's code you didn't post. There is definitely a difference between declaring with `let` and declaring with `var`. A `let` variable is scoped to the nearest enclosing `{ }` block, while a `var` declaration is scoped to the nearest enclosing `function` (or the global scope).